# Split data.frame into groups by column name

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

I'm new to R. I have a data frame with column names of such type:

```
file_001   file_002   block_001   block_002   red_001   red_002 ....etc'  
  0.05       0.2        0.4         0.006       0.05       0.3
  0.01       0.87       0.56        0.4         0.12       0.06
```

I want to split them into groups by the column name, to get a result like this:

```
group_file
file_001   file_002
  0.05       0.2
  0.01       0.87

group_block
block_001   block_002
  0.4        0.006
  0.56       0.4

group_red
red_001    red_002
  0.05       0.3
  0.12       0.06

...etc'
```

My file is huge. I don't have a certain number of groups.
It needs to be just by the column name's start.

Comment: Relevant: [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158589/4891738)

Answer (score 8):

In base R, you can use `sub` and `split.default` like this to return a list of data.frames:

```
myDfList <- split.default(dat, sub("_\\d+", "", names(dat)))
```

this returns

```
myDfList
$block
  block_001 block_002
1      0.40     0.006
2      0.56     0.400

$file
  file_001 file_002
1     0.05     0.20
2     0.01     0.87

$red
  red_001 red_002
1    0.05    0.30
2    0.12    0.06
```

`split.default` will split data.frames by variable according to its second argument. Here, we use `sub` and the regular expression "_\d+" to remove the underscore and all numeric values following it in order to return the splitting values "block", "file", and "red".

As a side note, it is typically a good idea to keep these data.frames in a list and work with them through functions like `lapply`. See gregor's answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for some motivating examples.

Comment: the results I got are: 

'$file_001
file_001   
 0.05
 0.01

$file_002
file_002
   0.2
  0.87'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you lmo,
after using your code, it didn't work as I wanted, but I came with a solution thanks to your guidance.

So, in order to divide a Data Frame list:

```
myDfList <- split.default(dat, sub(x = as.character(names(dat)), pattern = "\\_.*", ""))
```

hope it'll help people in the future!